# How do scripts with content and sources work?

Tags: javascript

I was just wondering how the following works:

```
<script src="url">
 content
</script>
```

Sorry if this is way too simple. I am a beginner at js.

Comment: May want to read this (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)